# removing a sub string with digits and a dash in between a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-re

I have been trying to remove a sub string with digits from a string with no success

string:

```
All in the Family 01-01 - Meet the Bunkers.mp4
```

Desired result:

```
All in the Family - Meet the Bundkers.mp4
```

keep in mind I am trying to run this code:

```
import os
import re

templist = []
templist1 = []
templist2 = []
numlist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("E:\Plex Content\TV Shows\All in the Family (Complete TV Series in MP4 format)"):
    for file in files:
        templist.append(file.replace(' ' + r'\d\d' + '-' + r'\d\d' + ' ', ''))

print(templist)
```

any help would be appreicated

Thanks,

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to delete two digits followed by a dash followed by two more digits and white space, the following regular expression substitution works:

```
re.sub(r"\d{2}-\d{2}\s", "", file)
#'All in the Family - Meet the Bunkers.mp4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's going on with your code but if the only requirement is to remove the numbers and the "-" in between I would do it like this

```
import re
s = "All in the Family 01-01 - Meet the Bunkers.mp4"
pattern = '[0-9]'
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s[:-4]) + s[-4:]
s = s.replace("-","",1)
print(s)
```

- Output : All in the Family  - Meet the Bunkers.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Before using a pattern, it's useful compile it for faster working.

```
patern = re.compile(r'\d+-\d+\s*')
file = patern.sub("", file)
#'All in the Family - Meet the Bunkers.mp4'
```

Comment: If providing an answer, you should comment on what you did and how this will work regarding the OP. And a good explanation will most of the time be voted up and chosen as the answer for this post.